# InitContainer read-only issues in configuring vm.max_map_count

Tags: kubernetes, init

An init container is unable to get completed. It's giving me a `sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count": Read-only file system` error

```
initContainers:
  - name: sysctl
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=1677720']
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

And when I add `runAsUser: 0`, I get `Error: container's runAsUser breaks non-root policy`

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this working?